# Does Boto support the map and list DynamoDB types, and JSON document type?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto

Could someone, please, confirm whether or not at present (Apr. 2015) Boto supports the DynamoDB JSON document, and map and list datatypes?

If yes, could someone provide simple code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document support (JSON), including Map, List, Boolean, and Null types was introduced in the boto library at [this commit](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/35656b52572b72d969cb77fde5cf6ea02189440a#diff-4fbc9a8db33f19d0f316dbff4119982cR11). You can find examples of how to use the new data types later in [this commit](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/35656b52572b72d969cb77fde5cf6ea02189440a#diff-0f2de36188c2897ec470670e64251681R45).

Comment: Dear Alexander, Thank you so much for providing the information I was looking for. Do you have any pointers to code that creates an Item of a Table, that has a column of type M and that is populated with a Python dictionary? And another example, of getting the item from this table and using DocumentPath() (or its Boto equivalent) to retrieve only just a wanted part of the document? Something similar to the Java code that Jeff Barr describes in the Amazon blog: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/  ? Any such Boto example would be extremely valuable.

Comment: Are there any examples available that anyone has found for using Boto for this purpose?